# TinyMCE - edit of image url

Tags: javascript, image, image-uploading, tinymce-4

I use TinyMCE editor on my website. When I want to upload some image from my computer I use [image]

this icon to upload an image. The problem is, that in "source" field it give address like this: "blob:http://www.recension4u.com/be4ba2df-77ee-4c9a-8dd7-5cbb2f273b3b" and after uploading the image has stupid address like this: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QAiRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAQESAAMAAAABAAEAAAAAAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwM..."

and so on, and an image doesn' t shown. Please, can you help me, what I must edit in myTinyMCE code, if I want image address like this: "http://www.recension4u.com/images/image.png". For all advice thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably use  `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` for read your file and this create a base 64 of your input. You can use `urlFile = URL.createObjectURL(f);` instead to get a proper url.